# Get the MAC address i'm using to connect to internet, in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mac-address

I'm using [macaddress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/macaddress), but I don't know how to get the mac address what I'm using to connect to the internet

```
const macaddress = require('macaddress');

macaddress.all(function (err, all) {
  console.log("Your mac address is -->" + JSON.stringify(all, null, 2));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try .one function for one interface

```
require('node-macaddress').one(function (err, addr) { console.log(addr); }
```

On node ≥ 0.11 you are not required to use the asynchronous version
try

```
var addr = require('node-macaddress').one();
```